# how to upgrade new table an existing apps?

Tags: android, sqlite

Friends,

I have an existing apps published and during an upgrade, I want to add a new table to my database, but also not lose the data from the other tables when upgrading the application. Can someone tell me, (but if you could show me some example also) of how this is done and how to test it. Because I've looked through the forums but mainly there are discussions about adding a new column etc. I figured that I have to do it somehow with alter table, but I did not understand everything. If you can tell me the steps of this process I would really appreciate it.I have used DBAdapter class extends SQLiteOpenHelper.Accept my question and asap give me solution..

Comment: Why is this difficult. Follow the same tutorials. You just need to add another CREATE sql query in onUpgrade method of thesqlhelper class.

Comment: when onUpgrade method called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything happens in your class `DBAdapter`. There you must implement a method `onUpgrade` which adds your new table to the database. Here is a skeleton for doing this:

```
class DBAdapter extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    // Implement the other methods

    // This method is called when your application is being upgraded. 
    public void inUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        Log.i(TAG, "adding table to the database") ;
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE MyNewTable(_id INTEGER, name TEXT)") ;
        Log.i(TAG, "upgrade done") ;
    }
```

You may look at the documentation of the class [SQLiteOpenHelper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html)